# RadiobuttonFor always selecting default value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

There are two RadiobuttonFor items in the list. One with a value of "Yes" and the other with a value of "No". When selecting yes, a section of the page will be visible and when selecting "No" that section should not display.

The problem I'm facing is that even if "No" is selected the value that pulls through to Javascript is "Yes". Regardless of the option chosen the value is always "Yes".

I've tried multiple ways of getting the value in a different way, but always end up with the same result with the value being pulled through as "Yes".

Is there some different way of pulling though the correct value?

MVC HTML:

```
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <label class="btn btn-radio">
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Claims, "Yes", new { name = "radClaim" }) Yes
                                    </label>

                                    <label class="btn btn-radio">
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Claims, "No", new { name = "radClaim" }) No
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Claims, null, new { id = "clmError" })
                            </div>
```

Javascript:
this.value and var selected is always "Yes" even if No is selected.

```
     $("input[name='Claims']").on("change", function () {
    var selected = $("input[name='Claims']:checked").val()
 
    if (this.value === "Yes") {
        $("#showClaimsHistory").show();
        if (claimCount > 0) {
            $("#showClaimList").show();
        }

    } else {
        $("#showClaimsHistory").hide();
        $("#showClaimList").hide();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
[data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn input[type="radio"],
[data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn-group > .btn input[type="radio"],
[data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn input[type="checkbox"],
[data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn-group > .btn input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
}


    .btn {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;


white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn.focus {
  color: #555555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  outline: 0;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
a.btn.disabled,
fieldset[disabled] a.btn {
  pointer-events: none;
     }

.btn-radio {
/*border-radius: 30px;*/
border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 600;
/* padding: .75em 1em; */
text-align: center;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
min-width: 110px;
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
line-height: 40px;
height: 60px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: none;
padding-left: 4.2em !important;
padding-right: 4.2em !important;
margin-right: 1.2em !important;
 }

.btn-radio:hover {
    background: #1e73e9 !important;
    border: 1px solid #1e73e9 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

------------ Edit -------------

Results after adding solution from below:
[image]

The value that is passed through when the javascript runs:
[image]

Comment: remove this code new { name = "radClaim" } from two radiobutton

Comment: @meysam asadi, I've removed that code, but it's still didn't resolve

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
 $("input[name='Claims']").on("change", function () {
    var selected = $("input[name='Claims']:checked").val()
 
    if (selected === 'Yes') {
        $("#showClaimsHistory").show();
        if (claimCount > 0) {
            $("#showClaimList").show();
        }

    } else {
        $("#showClaimsHistory").hide();
        $("#showClaimList").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I've edited with the results coming after adding this as a solution. It's still coming through with a value of "Yes"

Comment: hmm something is wrong in your dropdown selection syntax that's why it always pick YES

Comment: The dropdown is populated from a database. However, the yes/no radio buttons is actioning before that. If No is selected the it should hide the history and list (no action required on them)... All other actions are working fine (selecting from dropdown/saving/removing), its only the radio button with the yes/no where the issue is coming from

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code, Probably interferes with either the script or the css file, I need to see Radiobutton css file.

try this

```
<div data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-radio">
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Claims, "Yes", new { customValue = "Yes" }) Yes
      </label>

      <label class="btn btn-radio">
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Claims, "No", new { customValue = "No" }) No
      </label>
</div>
```

script

```
$("input[name='Claims']").on("change", function () {
     var selected = $("input[name='Claims']:checked").attr('customValue')

     if (selected === "Yes") {
        $("#showClaimsHistory").show();
        if (claimCount > 0) {
            $("#showClaimList").show();
        }

     } else {
            $("#showClaimsHistory").hide();
            $("#showClaimList").hide();
     }
});
```

Test this code I did not make any changes but it works fine

```css
[data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn input[type="radio"],
[data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn-group > .btn input[type="radio"],
[data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn input[type="checkbox"],
[data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn-group > .btn input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
}


    .btn {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;


white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn.focus {
  color: #555555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  outline: 0;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
a.btn.disabled,
fieldset[disabled] a.btn {
  pointer-events: none;
     }

.btn-radio {
/*border-radius: 30px;*/
border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 600;
/* padding: .75em 1em; */
text-align: center;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
min-width: 110px;
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
line-height: 40px;
height: 60px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: none;
padding-left: 4.2em !important;
padding-right: 4.2em !important;
margin-right: 1.2em !important;
 }

.btn-radio:hover {
    background: #1e73e9 !important;
    border: 1px solid #1e73e9 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <label class="btn btn-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="male" name="Claims" value="Yes">
                                        Yes
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="Famele" name="Claims" value="No">
                                        No
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                                <script>
                                $("input[name='Claims']").on("change", function () {
    var selected = $("input[name='Claims']:checked").val()
    alert(selected);
    if (this.value === "Yes") {
        

    } else {
        
    }
});
                                </script>
```

Comment: added css for the radio buttons as an edit to the question

Comment: This is working to hide / show what is needed, however it is not binding to the model when submitting. The model passed into the controller still holds the "Yes"value. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Test this code I did not make any changes but it works fine

Comment: It should work, maybe because of the scripts in the program.

Comment: change your code to this :@Html.RadioButton("Claims", "Yes", new { id = "rdbYes"})        @Html.RadioButton("Claims", "No", new { id = "rdbNo"})